# EC2 instance with AWS certificate manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I am new to AWS. I have created an EC2 instance for some application i am working on and linked it to a Route 53 record set(ex: test.example.com). In this record set, I am using type A and used the public IPv4 of my application. I tried creating a new SSL certificate using certificate manager and it has created a new record set with (_9871497819.test.example.com). How can i use the certificate record set to my application? Do i have to remove the old instance(test.example.com)? if yes, how can i link the EC2 instance to the new record set? 
PS: The URLs used are just for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement a load balancer in order to use your certificate with an ec2 instance.

> Although you install your website on an Amazon EC2 instance, you cannot directly deploy an ACM Certificate on that instance. You must instead deploy your certificate by using one of the services integrated with ACM. For more information see Services Integrated with AWS Certificate Manager.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/setup-website.html